# Int32 vs Float64 performances in Crystal

Tags: performance, crystal-lang

I ran this benchmark and I was very surprised to see that Crystal performances are almost the same for Int32 or Float64 operations.

```
$ crystal benchmarks/int_vs_float.cr --release
  int32 414.96M (  2.41ns) (±14.81%)  0.0B/op        fastest
float64 354.27M (  2.82ns) (±12.46%)  0.0B/op   1.17× slower
```

Do I have some weird side effects on my benchmark code?

```
require "benchmark"

res = 0
res2 = 0.0

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("int32") do
    a = 128973 / 119236
    b = 119236 - 128973

    d = 117232 > 123462 ? 117232 * 123462 : 123462 / 117232

    res = a + b + d
  end

  x.report("float64") do
    a = 1.28973 / 1.19236
    b = 1.19236 - 1.28973

    d = 1.17232 > 1.23462 ? 1.17232 * 1.23462 : 1.23462 / 1.17232

    res = a + b + d
  end
end

puts res
puts res2
```

Comment: questions must be self-contained, with the code embedded in the question itself, not in an external link

Comment: I can't because it's too much code compare to the actual question "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Fixed. The snippet is smaller now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all `/` in Crystal is float division, so this is largely comparing floats:

```
typeof(a) # => Float64
typeof(b) # => Int32
typeof(d) # => Float64 | Int32)
```

If we fix the benchmark to use integer division, `//`, I get:

```
  int32 631.35M (  1.58ns) (± 5.53%)  0.0B/op   1.23× slower
float64 773.57M (  1.29ns) (± 3.21%)  0.0B/op        fastest
```

Still no real difference, within error margin. Why's that? Let's dig deeper. First we can extract the examples into a not inlinable function and make sure to call it so Crystal doesn't just ignore it:

```
@[NoInline]
def calc
  a = 128973 // 119236
  b = 119236 - 128973
  d = 117232 > 123462 ? 117232 * 123462 : 123462 // 117232

  a + b + d
end
p calc
```

Then we can build this with `crystal build --release --no-debug --emit llvm-ir` to obtain an `.ll` file witht the optimized LLVM-IR. We dig out our `calc` function and see something like this:

```
define i32 @"*calc:Int32"() local_unnamed_addr #19 {
alloca:
  %0 = tail call i1 @llvm.expect.i1(i1 false, i1 false)
  br i1 %0, label %overflow, label %normal6

overflow:                                         ; preds = %alloca
  tail call void @__crystal_raise_overflow()
  unreachable

normal6:                                          ; preds = %alloca
  ret i32 -9735
}
```

Where's all our calculations gone? LLVM did them at compile time because it was all constants! We can repeat the experiment with the `Float64` example:

```
define double @"*calc:Float64"() local_unnamed_addr #11 {
alloca:
  ret double 0x40004CAA3B35919C
}
```

A little less boilerplate, hence it being slightly faster, but again, all precomputed!

I'll end the exercise here. Further research for the reader:

- What happens if we try to introduce non constant terms into all expressions?
- Is the premise that 32bit integer operations should be any faster or slower than 64bit IEEE754 floating point operations on a modern 64bit CPU sane?

Comment: Thanks you very much for this clear and very useful answer! I just tried with your advises and there is still no difference between the int and float versions. I saw that the calcint32 method is almost 50 instructions long while the calcfloat64 is only 11 instructions. Also I saw this post https://www.quora.com/In-CPUs-how-much-slower-is-floating-point-arithmetic-than-integer-arithmetic-Is-the-main-difference-in-divisions, as far as I understand float division could be faster than integer division on some hardware.